# Making a private member out of an object in another class

Tags: java

Edit: I pasted the wrong code have updated it

I have created 3 concrete classes, the first two have been completed and work fine. The third one needs to have **private members of new objects of the other two classes**. How do I write the code for this for the private members? My existing classes are NameAddress and PhoneNumber, the new one is named ContactDetails and the two already created classes are NameAddress and PhoneNumber (I need one of the first and two of the latter for my private members)

I have tried:

```
public class ContactDetails{
  private Object contactName = new NameAddress();
  private Object mobile = new PhoneNumber();
  private Object home = new PhoneNumber();
}
```

but this doesn't work in the compiler and throws up an error. Help would be appreciated, I just can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Comment: I think you should show the part of code that causes error. This does not seem to cause an compile time error assuming you have right curly brace actually in the code but not here.

Comment: @user1599706 please post the exact error message from the compiler

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious syntax errors aside from a missing `}` to close the class:

```
public class ContactDetails {
    private Object contactName = new NameAddress();
} // ← here
```

but perhaps you'd like to declare the `contactName` field as something a bit more useful than `Object`?

```
public class ContactDetails {
    private NameAddress contactName = new NameAddress();
}
```

---

If that doesn't help, please tell us exactly what the compiler error message is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your classes don't have the no-args constructor. If you've defined constructors that take arguments, then add this to your `NameAddress` class:

```
public NameAddress() {
}
```

And do the same for `PhoneNumber``

This should eliminate the compiler error (but may not lead to a *working* application)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but I think you may have misread your specifications.

When you say:

> The third [class] needs to have private members of new objects of the other two classes.

...then this implies that you are declaring, and later instantiating, the two different object types in your class.  When you need to access them via an accessor, you need to be explicit about what type you're returning.  When you're modifying them via a mutator, you *must* be specific about what object you're modifying - unless you're absolutely consistent with what this particular `Object` represents, you run the risk of losing object state information and causing aberrant behavior with your program.

Here's an example. This code works okay as long as `setS()` is passed a String:

```
public class Test {
    private Object s = new String("Testing");

    public Object getS() {
        return (String) s;
    }

    public void setS(Object theS) {
        s = theS;
    }
}
```

...but if I pass in anything that's a subclass of Object (that is to say, ***anything*** instantiated with `new`), I will get a `ClassCastException`.

The proper way to mitigate this would be to specifically instantiate/return/pass in a String.

```
public class Test {
    private String s = new String("Testing");

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String theS) {
        s = theS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `new String("Testing")` and not `"Testing"`?

Comment: To belabor the point that `String` is an `Object`.  You can do it either way and it'll have the same results, of course.